# Codeigniter, routes and 404 error

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

this are my routes.php

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'base/index/$1';
$route['home'] = 'base/home';
$route['operativa/(:any)'] = 'base/operativa/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = "base";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

This is my controller, base:

```
class Base extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();      
        $this->load->model('filesmodel', 'files');
        $this->load->model('cestamodel', 'cesta');
    }
    public function index ($pagina = 'login')  {
        $data = array(
            'page' => $pagina,
            'logado' => false
        );
        $this->load->view('modules/top', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$pagina, $data);
        $this->load->view('modules/bottom', $data);
    }
    public function home (){
        $pagina = 'home';
        $data = array(
            'page' => $pagina,
            'logado' => true,
            'notifications' => 3
        );
        $this->load->view('modules/top', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$pagina, $data);
        $this->load->view('modules/bottom', $data);
    }
    public function operativa($tipo){
        echo 'El tipo es: '.$tipo.'<br>';
        switch ($tipo) {
            case 'nuevo_cliente':
                $pagina = $tipo;
                break;
            case 'contacto':
                $pagina = $tipo;
                break;
            case 'mensajes':
                $pagina = $tipo;
                break;
        }
        $data = array(
            'page' => $pagina,
            'logado' => true,
            'notifications' => 2
        );
        $this->load->view('modules/top', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/operativa/'.$pagina, $data);
        $this->load->view('modules/bottom', $data);
    }
}
```

Problem is that, url:

```
/operativa/nuevo_cliente
```

Will fire 404 instead of the echo

Any idea wha am I missing?

PD: index and home work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that your URL is matching the first route, so it never gets to the function you want it to go.

You should rewrite your routes from more specific to more general, like so:

```
$route['home'] = 'base/home';
$route['operativa/(:any)'] = 'base/operativa/$1';
$route['(:any)'] = 'base/index/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = "base";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Comment: But shouldn't it be matched at least by `(:any)/(:any)`??

Comment: you mean "operativa/(:any)"? if so, no, because it will match "(:any)" first and then stop processing rules.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `echo 'El tipo es: '.$tipo.'<br>';` must be after the switch statment.
And why do you echo this in your controller ?
And do an if statment instead of switch.

Comment: I just want to know if the function is executed, its for debugging purposes, but; As I comment in my answer a 404 is fired instead

Comment: This is your default controller ?

Comment: So i gues that your link to nuevo_cliente is this :

base/operativo/nuevo_cliente

Comment: It doesn't work either, but I am not using base/ ( just base/operativo/nuevo_cliente

Comment: Print the data your passing into the view

Comment: The thing is the controller, it doesn't even recognise; the echo will never happen, so anything that comes next, either..

Answer (score 0):

EDIT!!! You don't need the switch statment...Try this and see  what happens (just for testing):

```
public function operativa($pagina){

 if ( ! file_exists('application/views/pages/operativa/'.$pagina.'.php'))
{
    // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
    show_404();
}
    $data = array(
            'page' => $pagina,
            'logado' => true,
            'notifications' => 2
    );
    $this->load->view('modules/top', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/operativa/'.$pagina, $data);
    $this->load->view('modules/bottom', $data);
}
```

You could also change the order of the routes like this :

```
$route['operativa/(:any)'] = 'base/operativa/$1';
$route['(:any)'] = 'base/index/$1';
$route['home'] = 'base/home';
$route['default_controller'] = "base";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Comment: Its a simplified version of my code, I will need it later.. anyways, just a simple echo won't happen... I think the problem is in my routes?